# Android : How to OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE but preserve one particular field

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have a DAO in Android Room, with OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE on insert, there's a boolean field `downloaded`, which gets changed to true if this object was downloaded by the user,  I want to replace the whole object onConflict, but preserve the state of this field(`downloaded`) in the db.

```
public interface DAOTemplate<T> {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    @NonNull
    void insert(T... messages);

    @Delete
    void delete(T message);

    @Update
    void update(T message);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit late for the answer but I just did the same in my code. Your approach should be not to replace the object but update the existing one with the fields you need to update and just keep the downloaded.

For this use `OnConflictStrategy.FAIL`. Surround your `insert()` with `try/catch` block and then in catch put your `update()` call. I am using RXJava + Kotlin to so but you can implement this logic with any other async approach.

```
fun saveItem(item: Item): Single<Unit>? =
            Single.fromCallable {
                try {
                    dao.save(item)
                } catch (exception: SQLiteConstraintException) {
                    dao.updateModel(item.id)
                } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
                    dao.updateModel(item.id)
                }
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

And in DAO I am implementing `update` as follows:

```
@Query("UPDATE name_of_your_table SET quantity = quantity + 1 WHERE id = :id")
fun updateModel(id: String)
```

Here I am increasing the quantity but you can pass fields to update as params and use `SET` to set all fields you need to update.

Comment: That is very proper, I'll try this.

Comment: I think this is not practical if you have a lot of fields to update and only one or two fields to ignore

Answer (score 2):

I also needed a solution to preserve some fields when updating room db. Thank you very much @Rainmaker, I extended @Rainmaker solution. I know it is too late but I want to drop my solution here for future needs.

```
override suspend fun upsertItem(item: YourItem) {
    try{
        itemDao.insertItem(item)
    }catch (exception: SQLiteConstraintException){
        val oldItem = itemDao.getItemByIdOneShot(item.id)
        itemDao.updateItem(item.apply {
            downloaded = oldItem.downloaded
            // you can add more fields here
        })
    }catch (throwable: Throwable){
        val oldItem = itemDao.getItemByIdOneShot(item.id)
        itemDao.updateItem(item.apply {
            downloaded = oldItem.downloaded
            // you can add more fields here
        })
    }
}
```

Here is my Dao

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
abstract suspend fun insertItem(item: YourItem)

@Update
abstract suspend fun updateItem(item: YourItem)

@Query("select * from items where id= :id")
abstract fun getItemByIdOneShot(id: Int): YourItem
```